# withUnsafePointers is unavailable

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, pointers

I am trying to upgrade the following code from swift 2 to 3 and I get withUnsafePointers is unavailable: use nesterd withUnsafePointer instead. I have tried it a couple ways but I can't get it right. He is my code

```
  var v: LinphoneManager = self
  var lct: LinphoneCoreVTable = LinphoneCoreVTable()
       let theLinphoneCore : OpaquePointer = withUnsafePointers(&lct, &v, { (ptr: UnsafePointer<LinphoneCoreVTable>, selfPtr: UnsafePointer<LinphoneManager>) -> OpaquePointer in

                let voidPtr: UnsafeMutableRawPointer = unsafeBitCast(selfPtr, to: UnsafeMutableRawPointer.self)
             return linphone_core_new_with_config (ptr, self.configDb!, voidPtr /* user_data */)
        })
```

Comment: did you figure this out? I had something like this, already did the nested unsafe pointers but getting another problem with lct property.

Answer (score 2):

The error message:

> withUnsafePointers is unavailable: use nested withUnsafePointer instead

means to replace the call to withUnsafePointers (which takes two items and creates pointers to each) with two calls to `withUnsafePointer`, one inside the other's closure, each taking one item and creating a pointer to it.

So this:

```
withUnsafePointers(&a, &b) { aPtr, bPtr in
    // do something with aPtr and bPtr
}
```

Becomes this:

```
withUnsafePointer(&a) { aPtr in
    withUnsafePointer(&b) { bPtr in
        // do something with aPtr and bPtr
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have tried to convert my original withUnsafePointers to withUnsafePointer and I can't get it right.

Comment: Then show what you've tried, and the problems (errors? incorrect behavior?) you're getting.

Comment: @rickster I did the nested unsafepointer, but I am having another problem with the &a param. Canot pass immutable value of type 'inout T' (aka inout _T') as inout argument.

Answer (score 0):

I use linphone in a project I just updated to swift3. This is what I updated those lines to. Seems to be working well. Hope this helps!

```
var lct: LinphoneCoreVTable = LinphoneCoreVTable()
        theLinphoneCore = withUnsafePointer(to: &lct) { (ptr: UnsafePointer<LinphoneCoreVTable>) -> OpaquePointer in
            let selfPtr: BTVoipService = self
            let voidPtr: UnsafeMutableRawPointer = unsafeBitCast(selfPtr, to: UnsafeMutableRawPointer.self)
            return linphone_core_new_with_config (ptr, self.configDb!, voidPtr /* user_data */)
        }
```